# Create configurable Spring ApplicationContext Hierarchy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, domain-driven-design

What I am basically trying to do, ist to build a Webapp with multiple ApplicationContexts. This is achievable with the SpringApplicationBuilder. The problem I face is, you have to "hard-code" all ApplicationContexts in your Spring-Boot Application (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html#boot-features-fluent-builder-api)

I´m looking for a way to load the ApplicationContexts of the child-modules per configuration? I want to include and exclude modules for specific maven-builds. Is this possible? The modules are each independent from each other, as we are using a Domain-Driven-Approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a command line argument to decide on which module to run.

```
public enum Module {
  MODULE1(Context1.class), MODULE2(Context2.class), MODULE3(Context3.class);
  Module(Class contextClass) ...
}

SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder()
    .sources(Parent.class)
    .bannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
String[] modules = args[0].split(",");
for(int i = 0; i < modules.length; i++){
  builder.child(Module.valueOf(modules[i]).contextClass);
}
builder.run(args);
```

In the simple example above, you can give comma separated modules to the startup like:
`mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments=module2,module3`